# Creating a tree from self referential tables in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm building a basic CMS in flask for an iPhone oriented site and I'm having a little trouble with something. I have a very small database with just 1 table (pages). Here's the model:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("pages.id"), nullable=True)
```

As you can see, for sub pages, they just reference another page object in the `parent_id` field. What I'm trying to do in the admin panel is have a nested unordered list with all the pages nested in their parent pages. I have very little idea on how to do this. All i can think of is the following (which will only work (maybe—I haven't tested it) 2 levels down):

```
pages = Page.query.filter_by(parent_id=None)
for page in pages:
    if Page.query.filter_by(parent_id=page.id):
        page.sub_pages = Page.query.filter_by(parent_id=page.id)
```

I would then just format it into a list in the template. How would I make this work with potentially over 10 nested pages?

Thanks heaps in advance!

---

**EDIT:** I've looked around a bit and found http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#adjacency-list-relationships, so I added

```
children = db.relationship("Page", backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=id))
```

to the bottom of my `Page` model. and I'm looking at recursively going through everything and adding it to a tree of objects. I've probably made no sense, but that's the best way I can describe it

---

**EDIT 2:** I had a go at making a recursive function to run through all the pages and generate a big nested dictionary with all the pages and their children, but it keeps crashing python so i think it's just an infinite loop... here's the function

```
def get_tree(base_page, dest_dict):
    dest_dict = { 'title': base_page.title, 'content': base_page.content }
    children = base_page.children
    if children:
        dest_dict['children'] = {}
        for child in children:
            get_tree(base_page, dest_dict)
    else:
        return
```

and the page i'm testing it with:

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    pages = Page.query.filter_by(parent_id=None)
    pages_dict = {}
    for page in pages:
        get_tree(page, pages_dict)
    return str(pages_dict)
```

anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at http://sqlamp.angri.ru/index.html

or http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/examples/adjacency_list/adjacency_list.py

**UPD:** For adjacency_list.py declarative example

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)

class TreeNode(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tree'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tree.id'))
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)

    children = relationship('TreeNode',

                        # cascade deletions
                        cascade="all",

                        # many to one + adjacency list - remote_side
                        # is required to reference the 'remote' 
                        # column in the join condition.
                        backref=backref("parent", remote_side='TreeNode.id'),

                        # children will be represented as a dictionary
                        # on the "name" attribute.
                        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('name'),
                    ) 

    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent

    def append(self, nodename):
        self.children[nodename] = TreeNode(nodename, parent=self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "TreeNode(name=%r, id=%r, parent_id=%r)" % (
                    self.name,
                    self.id,
                    self.parent_id
                )
```

Fix recursion

```
def get_tree(base_page, dest_dict):
    dest_dict = { 'title': base_page.title, 'content': base_page.content }
    children = base_page.children
    if children:
        dest_dict['children'] = {}
        for child in children:
            get_tree(child, dest_dict)
    else:
        return
```

Use query in example for recursive fetch data from db:

```
 # 4 level deep
 node = session.query(TreeNode).\
                        options(joinedload_all("children", "children", 
                                                "children", "children")).\
                        filter(TreeNode.name=="rootnode").\
                        first()
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's still a little over my head. for the second link is there a wak to do that with the declarative base way of defining models (that's what the flask extension for sqlalchemy uses)?

Comment: @Estin That joinedload_all call specifies "children" N times. In this case 4, and so the tree will only recurse 4 times.

Is there any way to make it recurse an arbitrary amount of times? Unless there is a programmatic way to determine it easily?

Comment: @Zoran, if you planned works with trees recursions this is are not  best choice, more powerful ways is using MPTT solutions like http://sqlalchemy-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

> Unless there is a programmatic way to determine it easily? - You can store on root node his "deep level".

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic - it is more than year since you asked your question however I thought I will give you another hint. You can simply fetch all rows in one query (that is with no `options(joinedload_all(...))` and then build your tree basing on parent_id. I'm guessing you won't have milions of elements (i.e. how many pages would you have? 100? even 1000?) so such query should not pose any issues from database performance point of view. And also traversing such array to build your tree should not be too resources-hungry.

Comment: What's the difference between a `cascade` argument within `relationship`, and a `ONDELETE` argument within a `foreignkey` function setting to `CASCADE`?

Comment: Since this post, `joinedload_all` [has been deprecated](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload_all) and will be removed in a future release.