# Flask SQL-Alchemy creating hierarchy table many foreign keys to same table

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Have got a roles table:

```
from datetime import datetime
# from models.user_role import UserRoleModel
from models.role_hierarchy import RoleHierarchyModel


class RoleModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "security_role"
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    role = db.relationship('UserRoleModel', back_populates='role')

    parent_role = db.relationship('RoleHierarchyModel',
                                  back_populates='parent_role',
                                  primaryjoin="RoleHierarchyModel.parent_role_id == RoleModel.role_id")
    child_role = db.relationship('RoleHierarchyModel',
                                 back_populates='child_role',
                                 primaryjoin="RoleHierarchyModel.child_role_id == RoleModel.role_id")
```

and a Roles Hierarchy table

```
class RoleHierarchyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "security_role_hierarchy"
    role_h_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('security_role.role_id'))
    child_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('security_role.role_id'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    parent_role = db.relationship('RoleModel', back_populates='parent_role'
                                  , foreign_keys='RoleHierarchyModel.parent_role_id')
    child_role = db.relationship('RoleModel', back_populates='child_role'
                                 , foreign_keys='RoleHierarchyModel.child_role_id')
```

Not sure if I have set this up correctly nor how to get it into the database correctly once I have done this.  What I want to create is a role called super user that has other roles associated with it

I try:

```
base_role = RoleModel(title='Read')
other_base_role = RoleModel(title='Write')

base_role.save_to_db()
other_base_role.save_to_db()

super_user = RoleModel(title='Super)
hierarchy1 = RoleHierarchyModel()
hierarchy2 = RoleHierarchyModel()

hierarchy1.child_role(base_role)
hierarchy2.child_role(other_base_role)

super_user.parent_role.append(hierarchy1)
super_user.parent_role.append(hierarchy2)
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original
exception was: Attempting to flush an item of type <class 'models.role.RoleModel'> as a member of collection "RoleModel.child_role". Expected an object of type <class 'models.role_hierarchy.RoleHierarchyModel'> or
 a polymorphic subclass of this type. (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/7s2a)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Firstly, you're allowing only one child role and one parent role, while you seem to be wanting to have multiple children and only one parent. That way, you get a tree structure, where one role has the rights of all it's child roles and maybe some extra rights just for themselves, right?

Comment: Yeah that is exactly it!  How would I go about specifying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer hidden in the SQLAlchemy documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths

Roles table now looks like:

```
class RoleModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "security_role"
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    role = db.relationship('UserRoleModel', back_populates='role')

    child_roles = db.relationship('RoleModel', secondary='security_role_hierarchy'
                                  , primaryjoin='RoleModel.role_id==RoleHierarchyModel.parent_role_id'
                                  , secondaryjoin="RoleModel.role_id==RoleHierarchyModel.child_role_id",
                                  backref="parent_roles")
```

and the hierarchy table is now:

```
class RoleHierarchyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "security_role_hierarchy"
    role_h_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('security_role.role_id'))
    child_role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('security_role.role_id'))
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, there should be no need to have two classes, which is kind of where your problem started.

To make this a proper tree, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896292/5015356). You only need to reference the parent_id through a column, and let SQLAlchemy get you the children through a `relationship` object.

Suppose you store the rights a role has in a list somehow. Then, if you want to see if someone has the right to do something, or if you want to return a list of all rights a person has (directly and indirectly):

```py
class Role:
   _rights = ['canChangePassword', 'canEditPosts', 'canDeletePosts'...]

   def has_right(self, rightName):
       if rightName in self._rights
           return True
       for child in self.children:
           if child.has_right(rightName):
               return True
       return False

   def get_rights(self):
       all_rights = self._rights
       for child in self.children:
           all_rights += self.children.get_rights()
       # there can be duplicates, cast to a set to remove them
       return list(set(all_rights))
```

I can also see how rights are granted based on the description or title, but in that case, just iterate the same way and construct a list of role titles from itself and all children. Use recursion to your advantage here.